# force ordering of specific columns in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with many columns.

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(100,1000))
```

I need to have two specific column, say `[793]` and `[642]` as the first ones, while the order of the others does not matter.

I could do

```
df.columns=[793,642,...the rest...]
```

However, my columns are variable, as well as the reference ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html) for all columns without specified in list with prepend list `L` for new columns names, last change ordering by subset by `[]`:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(100,1000))

L = [793, 642]

cols = L + df.columns.difference(L).tolist()
#another solution
#cols = np.concatenate([L, df.columns.difference(L)])
#list comprehension solution
#cols = L + [x for x in df.columns if not x in L]

df = df[cols]
print (df.head(2))
        793       642       0         1         2         3         4    \
0  0.462103  0.811223  0.491396  0.701752  0.494450  0.352717  0.345460   
1  0.840597  0.852080  0.681095  0.014459  0.963252  0.972862  0.490964   

        5         6         7      ...          990       991       992  \
0  0.718141  0.199168  0.379924    ...     0.279972  0.963898  0.987907   
1  0.151226  0.625833  0.428249    ...     0.069179  0.045112  0.328453   

        993       994       995       996       997       998       999  
0  0.402805  0.243648  0.624790  0.864440  0.653621  0.066524  0.072025  
1  0.894080  0.451285  0.538485  0.834018  0.926311  0.032849  0.095636  

[2 rows x 1000 columns]
```